# why command mv remove all the file?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to copy git.sh to ever file below /root 
Then I use this 
`mv git.sh /root/`
Is a mirecle that all the file below /root has been delete.

Could you explain what happen after the command?
what `mv git.sh /root/*` meaning?
Could you give me the right command to copy a file to ever file below /root/?

[image]

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: Use "cp" for copy, "mv" is for move.  Don't use wildcard char in destination - it has no meaning. * - mean all matches. mv /src/* /dest/ moves all files in source folder into dest folder. Move is a couple of operations copy + remove original. No miracles just as expected. gl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command `mv` moves files. When file in destination exists, it will be replaced. The right command to copy file is `cp`. It's used same way as `mv`.

Command `mv git.sh /root/*` will substitute wildcard char `*` with all names the directory contains. Then there are a few cases:

1. /root contains multiple files or directories: command will fail
2. /root contains one file: git.sh will be moved and replace the file in directory /root
3. /root is empty: git.sh will be moved as git.sh to /root

`mv` will remove source but `cp` keeps it.

It's better to have destination path with filename, for example `mv git.sh /root/git.sh`. When moving multiple files use destination path just to directory without filename or wildcard chars, for example `mv dir/* /root/`. When you want to move directory with subdirectories add `-R` argument.

Use `man mv` or `man cp` for more information.